# Apple Mach-O Linker Error - GameCenter

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, xcode

Anyone have any idea why gamecenter and IAP are bringing up this error?

[image: Mach-o Linker Error]

I don't think its an issue with my architectures as I have arm6, arm7 and i386

[image: Architectures]

Comment: running on simulator and device give similar errors.

Comment: What have you done so that this error is coming

Comment: After adding which thing, this error is coming

Comment: Not sure what may have caused this. I did click "fix errors" on the game center capabilities page

Comment: Go to target > build phases > compile sources > check all .m files are present here

Comment: check All frameworks are added here

Comment: yes, i checked that after reading a different SO question. they're all added.

Comment: just try restart xcode

Answer (score 0):

For Game Center you need to add GameKit framework, and for IAP you need StoreKit framework.

Add those, and clean your project, then try compiling it again.

Comment: Without adding those frameworks, would he even have reached the linker phase (as the headers would have been missing)?

Comment: @Till Not entirely sure. We'd would have to look at his project to confirm that. It looks like he's calling all the methods from `RootViewController` though.